# Is there a way to pass a jQuery function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to which I want to pass a custom jQuery function that was attached to the jQuery prototype: $.fn.

For example,

```
$.fn.customFx = function() {
  //do something...    
}

function foo(func1) {
  //do something...
  $(selector).func1();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  foo($.fn.customFx);
}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to pass the function name as a string. Try this.

```
$.fn.customFx = function() {
  //do something...    
}

function foo(func1) {
  //do something...
  $(selector)[func1]();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  foo('customFx');
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to pass the function name as a string when you can pass the function itself? See my answer.

Comment: @Tomalak - I agree with you but that is also one way of doing it.

Comment: Well, not really, as it requires hard-coding a function name. Passing in a function reference is much more versatile.

Comment: It is not hard-coing at all. While passing a function as a reference too you have to mention the function name.

Comment: Well, not really. ;) You could pass a variable that contains a function reference.

Comment: Same applies to string as well, you could pass a variable which contain function name as a string.

Comment: I agree with Tomalak, passing the function as an argument is more portable instead of passing it's name as a string. The function may not always have a name; think of anonymous functions, and even functions that don't exist in the global namespace - `foo.bar.myFunction()`

Answer (score 7):

```
function foo(func1) {
  func1.call( $(selector) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in the function name as a string

```
$.fn.customFx = function() {
  //do something...    
}

function foo( methodName ) {
  //do something...
  $(selector)[ methodName  ]();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  foo( "customFx" );
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the call/apply functions to call the function, but it's quite overhead here.

Comment: *"You have to pass in the function name as a string...Alternatively, you could use the call/apply"* So then you *don't* have to pass a string.